# How to use Auth0 refresh token to persistent login Firebase in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, jwt, firebase-authentication, auth0

I'm using React Native, Firebase and Auth0.

Firebase `id_token` generate by `/delegation` expires after 3600 seconds (Max in Auth0 add-on setting). That means I have to check if the token is expired and re-generate another `id_token` repeatedly.

Is there a better way to keep user logged in or just prolong Firebase `id_token`?

Comment: How are you checking if the token is expired?